Vuforia External driver AreaTargets
We want to use real wear (or any other device) to send video frames to Vuforia Engine based application via TCP sockets or WebRTC. Vuforia engine based application has custom driver to receive the data.
We don't have problems with model targets as it works only with video frames. We have problem with AreaTargets.
We tried to send positional data to driver using device sensors with no luck.
Different approach is to calculate camera position regarding to first model target (or just use world center mode set to First target). This approach gives no luck too.
So my questions are:
Where does the positional data for the driver come from in built in Vuforia Engine driver?
Is it taken from the device sensors themselves or is it produced in a different way (forexample from SLAM algorithm)?
What is the data format? For example, if we have a given camera position and rotation in Unity, how do we correctly transform this data to the format
needed by the driver. I know it is Vector3 for position and 3x3 Matrix for rotation but do the values have additional requirements?
Frame data and positional data are synchronized (same timestamp).
Has Area Targets any chance to work with this "remote" approach?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Vuforia Driver provides the ability to pass images and other relevant data like device poses to Vuforia Engine for processing. When driver is not enabled Vuforia Engine uses platform APIs internally to get images from the built-in (or USB) camera and device poses from platform trackers like ARKit and ARCore. When Vuforia Driver is in use the developer is responsible for providing this data. This allows integration of Engine with arbitrary data sources, but the developer is responsible for such integration and for making sure that the data is in the right format and of sufficient quality.
Description on how to pass Camera Image data and Device Pose data is available here https://developer.vuforia.com/library/platform-support/creating-custom-driver
More information on Device Pose requirements is available here https://developer.vuforia.com/library/platform-support/vuforia-support-custom-devices-using-vuforia-driver
One note of caution: driver Device Pose integration requires highly accurate poses from a modern 6 degree of freedom tracker like a highly integrated Visual Inertial SLAM system. This tracker should produce poses of quality comparable to integrated trackers like ARKit, ARCore, Hololens tracker, etc.. I am not aware of any RealWear device having such capabilities.
